# Flutter WebViewPlus gives an error: invalid constant value

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying this simple dart code for WebViewPlus:

@override
Widget build(context) {

```
return const Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: WebViewPlus(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      controller.loadString("<html lang=\"en\"><body>hello world</body></html>");
    },
  ),
);
```

}

I am getting an error on the (controller): Invalid constant value.

I of course modified Android and iOS folders as written in the documents.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anonymous functions can't be `const`.  Either make it a named function or just remove the `const`.

Comment: @jamesdlin but this is the official example on pub.dev...

Comment: Official example from where?  From https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_plus?  Your code does not match the examples there.  Regardless, if you did actually see this in an example, then that example is simply wrong.  Sometimes people make mistakes and don't actually test examples.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes it does. WebViewPlus(
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      controller.loadString(r"""
           <html lang="en">
            <body>hello world</body>
           </html>
      """);
    },
  )

Comment: @jamesdlin I only now understood you. I took the const before the scaffold off and it works. I am sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to remove the const before the Scaffold widget.